# Oraclize Ethereum Bridge incompatible with current node

Tags: go-ethereum, oracles

I am trying Oraclize with a private ethereum blockchain.

I downloaded the current version of ethereum-bridge and tried the active mode

```
node bridge -H localhost:8042 -a 1
```

I get the error

> Not compatible with v8.0.0 of nodejs, please use v6.9.1 or a lower
> version
>
> exiting...

Is there a workaround for this?

BTW: I tried commenting out the checkVersion function, it crashes with an error

> {"message":"Error: Account ","stack":"Error: Error: Account \n    at
> deployOraclize
> (/Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/bridge.js:525:16)\n    at
> /Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/bridge.js:425:33\n    at
> /Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/bridge.js:506:14\n    at
> Request._callback
> (/Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/lib/bridge-http.js:24:14)\n
> at Request.self.callback
> (/Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)\n
> at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)\n
> at Request.
> (/Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)\n
> at emitOne (events.js:115:13)\n    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)\n
> at IncomingMessage.
> (/Users/abc/code/blockchain/ethereum-bridge/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)\n
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:312:19)\n    at emitNone
> (events.js:110:20)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)\n
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)\n    at
> _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)"}
>
> Exiting...

Answer (score 1):

The message says you are using node 8, and the bridge it is not compatible with that version of node.

For development I use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to be able to switch between differente versions of node. But it also allow to run an application with an specific version of node. So I'd recommend to run bridge with node v6, and the rest of your application with node v8.

[Oraclize bridge](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge) explicitely disallow to be run with node v8. Perhaps it is not tested enough. You can file a issue in their github repo. Likely they will add support in the near future.